# Template instantiation and function selection at runtime

Tags: c++, templates, runtime

I'm quite new to c++ and I'm trying to achieve something a bit tricky, for which I can't seem to find a satisfiable solution.

Let's say I have these two functions:

```
template <class T1, class T2> void foo(T1 param1, T2 param2){...}; 
template <class T1, class T2> void bar(T1 param1, T2 param2){...};
```

And at runtime, I want to select on of these two functions, and instantiate it with some template types obtained from a user input, say a char `c`. So I could do something like:

```
double d;
float f;
switch(c) {
    case 'a':
        foo(d, f); break;
    case 'b':
        foo(f, d); break;
    case 'c':
        bar(d, f); break;
    case 'd':
        bar(f, d); break;
```

But this solution is ugly, not scalable (I want to be able to add more function, and more template parameters), etc. And also, I can't see a way to assign one of the functions `foo` or `bar` to a function pointer, as the template parameters are unknown before runtime.

So if someone can provide me with a nice, clean solution to this problem, I'd be very happy! Cheers.

**Edit** Let me clarify a few things.

I'm accessing *binary* files, in which the data can be stored as `floats` or `doubles`. Obviously, the program has no way of knowing this type, so the user has to specify it in some way.

Then some mathematical computation has to be done on the data loaded from the file. And there are several of these computation possible, represented above by the functions `foo` and `bar`.

So I would like the user to be able to specify the type of the data in the file *at runtime*, and then select a function to apply to the loaded data *at runtime too*. The `switch(c)` was just an illustration of how I thought the user could select such things.

Comment: can you give some background on what it is you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: What exactly is the pattern that the calls should follow (in relation to `c`)?

Comment: Templates don't work at runtime. You could make an `unordered_map<char, std::function<void(float, double)>` and call that based on the key.

Comment: `foo` and `bar` are not functions, they are function templates. You create functions from them by instantiating them. You cannot instantiate a template at run time. This is not a big problem, as you cannot get a type from a user. All user inputs in the world are streams of bytes. You can only try to convert a given stream of bytes to a value of some type that must be known in advance at compile time. Thus, you have a set of types at compile time that you can use to instantiate your templates.

Comment: The easiest solution would be to use only one internal representation - double - and convert only during file input/output. If that is not feasible then the next easiest thing is to define an abstract interface that does not mention floats or doubles (only file names, operation codes and memo types), a class template implementing that interface by operating on its stored data (including input/output), and a factory function that instantiates Processor<float,double>(filename) and so on based on some parameter. That should keep the fuss to a minimum.

Comment: Thanks to all for the constructive comments. It made me think about the architecture of the program, and I'm happy with the way I ended up solving the problem. I created a `template` function in which I'm calling `foo` or `bar`, and it's in the calling function that I `switch` on the type. I know it's more splitting the problem than actually solving it, but in this case I think it works well. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't take pointers to function templates, because they are not functions, but need to be instantiated before. You can get a pointer like this:

```
typedef void (*Tfkt_int_int)( int, int );
Tfkt_int_int Ptr = &foo<int,int>;
```

As you can see, you need to specify possible combinations of types.

If there is many, and you want cleaner code, you can put all functions that share the same signature into one map. (That is, you need one map per signature.) Then distinguish which map to use in a switch statement.

```
std::map<char, Tfkt_int_int> Map_int_int;
Map_int_int['a'] = &foo<int,int>;
Map_int_int['b'] = &bar<int,int>;
// more ...

typdef void (*Tfkt_int_double)( int, double );
std::map<char, Tfkt_int_double> Map_int_double;
Map_int_double['a'] = &foo<int,double>;
Map_int_double['b'] = &bar<int,double>;
// more ...
```

If you want only one map, and are willing to sacrifice some of type savety, you can cast around the parameter types. It might be not as much of a loss in you situation, since you read that data from a byte stream already.

```
template <class T1, class T2> void foo(char* param1, char* param2)
{
  T1 P1 = *(reinterpret_cast<T1*>( param1 ));
  T2 P2 = *(reinterpret_cast<T2*>( param2 ));
  // ...
};

typedef void (*Tfkt)( char*, char* );
std::map<char, Tfkt> Map;
Map['a'] = &foo<int,int>;
Map['b'] = &foo<int,double>;
// more ...
```

Then call as:

```
double d;
int i;
char c = 'b';
(*(Map[c]))( reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i), reinterpret_cast<char*>(&d) );
```

Comment: Your answer really helped me solve my problem, although I didn't exactly implemented it that way. Thanks!